# Visual Studio Django запуск по локальной сети

Tags: python, django

Хочу запустить `Django` в локально сети, что бы пользователи могли посмотреть и потестировать.
На `Open Server` c `PhP` все просто.
Читал про развертывание через `uWSGI`.
Есть ли более понятный и быстрый способ?
Запускаю для локального тестирования через `Visual Studio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Запускаю для локального тестирования через Visual Studio.

Такой вариант подойдёт только для написания кода и отладки. Для всего остального нужно так или иначе поднимать сервер. Либо тот же uWSGI, либо ещё что-то в связке с Python.